# Trajectory of two charges in free space

Tags: electromagnetism

I am talking about the "two-body problem" for charges. Apparently, for two identical particles $\mathbf{x,y}$, each with charge $q$ and mass $m$, ignoring the gravitational force, the equations of motion are 
$$
m\ddot {\mathbf x}=\frac{q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\mathbf{y-x}}{|\mathbf{y-x}|^3}+\frac{\mu_0 q^2}{4\pi} \frac{\dot{\mathbf x}\times(\dot{\mathbf y}\times(\mathbf{x-y})) }{|\mathbf{x-y}|^3}
$$
and a similar equation for $\mathbf y$. This is apparently more complicated than the two body problem of gravitational forces, because there is an additional term about the magnetic field generated by one of the particles.

Question: is there an analytic general solution to this differential equation? Or are there good approximations?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4875.pdf

Comment: @ Wolphramjonny Apparently the pdf only includes "infall" - the two particles travel on a straight line, and of course, not magnetic term should appear

Comment: oh, my fault!!!

Comment: "*This is apparently more complicated than the two body problem of gravitational forces*" - Not in GR.